# Finding list of word present in column of a Dataframe using Grepl in R

Tags: r, data.table, string-matching, grepl

I have a dataframe df:

```
df <- structure(list(page = c(12, 6, 9, 65),
text = structure(c(4L,2L, 1L, 3L), 
.Label = c("I just bought a brand new AudiA6", "Get 2 years engine replacement warranty on BMW X6", 
"Volkswagen is the parent company of BMW", "ToyotaCorolla is offering new car exchange offers"), 
class = "factor")), .Names = c("page","text"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Also, I have a list of word:

```
wordlist <- c("Audi", "BMW", "extended", "engine", "replacement", "Volkswagen", "company", "Toyota","exchange", "brand")
```

I looked for the words from wordlist are present in the column text or not by unlisting the text and using grepl.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, match := paste(wordlist[unlist(lapply(wordlist, function(x) grepl(x, text, ignore.case = T)))], collapse = ","), by = 1:nrow(df)]
```

The problem is, I want to find exact words of the wordlist present in Column text.
With grepl it also shows word with partial match, for example AudiA6 from text was also partially matched to word Audi present in wordlist. Also my dataframe is very big and using grepl take a lot time in running the code. Please, if possible recommend any other Approach to do so. I want something like this:

```
df <- structure(list(page = c(12, 6, 9, 65), 
text = structure(c(4L,2L, 1L, 3L), 
.Label = c("I just bought a brand new AudiA6", "Get 2 years engine replacement warranty on BMW X6", 
 "Volkswagen is the parent company of BMW", "ToyotaCorolla is offering new car exchange offers"),
class = "factor"), match = c("exchange", "BMW,engine,replacement", 
"brand", "BMW,Volkswagen,company")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `str_extract_all` from `stringr` after adding word boundaries (`\\b`) to each of the words you want to extract so only full matches are considered (and you need to collapse all words with `"|"` to indicate a "or"):

```
sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(df$text, paste("\\b", wordlist, "\\b", sep="", collapse="|")), paste, collapse=",")
# [1] "exchange"               "engine,replacement,BMW" "brand"                  "Volkswagen,company,BMW"
```

If you want to put it in your `data.table`:

```
df[, match:=sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(text, paste("\\b", wordlist, "\\b", sep="", collapse="|")), paste, collapse=",")]
df
#   page                                              text                  match
#1:   12 ToyotaCorolla is offering new car exchange offers               exchange
#2:    6 Get 2 years engine replacement warranty on BMW X6 engine,replacement,BMW
#3:    9                  I just bought a brand new AudiA6                  brand
#4:   65           Volkswagen is the parent company of BMW Volkswagen,company,BMW
```

Comment: Or for a slightly shorter pattern... `sprintf("\\b(%s)\\b", paste(wordlist, collapse="|"))`

Comment: @Frank indeed better :-)

Comment: How can I use this only for each new row added in the df. I am reading this data from a sql server. I want to implement this code only if a new row is added. Reason for this is that it takes a lot time to run on the whole database. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @Fraxxx you can put the indices of the rows in `i` place : `df[newrow1:nrow(df), match:=sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(text[newrow1:nrow(df)], ...)]`

Comment: @Cath I didn't got what you mentioned in the above comment. Can you update your answer. I didn't understand the indices of the rows in ith place. For example, I have 25000 rows and after sometime I will add 50 new row. Now, I have 25050 rows and again I will add more rows to the database. This will go on. So I want to implement this operation every time a new row is added to the database.

Comment: @Fraxxx I will not update in the answer as if I did, it will not match the question anymore. Each time you add new row, you just past the line with the indices. So, for example, when you add rowe 25001 to 25050, you just do `df[25001:25050, match:=sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(text[25001:25050], paste("\\b", wordlist, "\\b", sep="", collapse="|")), paste, collapse=",")]`

Comment: Sure, NP. I got that thing, But I have to manually change the ith row everytime a new row is added. I was wondering if there is any solution which can check if a new row is added to the table, if yes then implement the operation on these newly added rows.

Comment: @Fraxxx I guess you can keep track of the number of rows of you df and update if the new value is superior to "last_nrow". (But it's hard to tell without knowing exactly the context)